# Do JWs have vestments, clothing, or "sacred" or symbolic objects that are used for any particular occasion or position?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, clothing, vestments

Different denominations have different sacred items and garbs available for priests, bishops, and the like.

For example, [this Wikipedia article on vestments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestment) mentions that such liturgical garments are used by "Eastern Orthodox, Catholics (Latin Church and others), Anglicans, and Lutherans". And [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_clothing) shows some other garments worn by clergy in some denominations.

And then Mormons have the temple garments (a form of underwear) discussed in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_garment).

[This other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61046/do-these-videos-represent-jw-meetings-or-do-they-have-other-secret-sacred-meetin) led me to check the YouTube videos of Jehovah's Witnesses meetings but I did not see any specific clothing or other items present in those.

Do Jehovah's Witnesses have any specific garments (e.g. underwear) or sacred/symbolic objects used for any particular occasion or church position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Jehovah's Witnesses don't have any special garments, nor is there a [clergy class](https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/no-paid-clergy/).

They do [try to dress up](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/jehovahs-will/dress-and-grooming/) for their ministry and Kingdom Hall meetings, according to the principle at [1 Timothy 2:9, 10](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/study-bible/books/1-timothy/2/#v54002009-v54002010). Different cultures will have different expectations for what constitutes "appropriate" and "modest" dress and grooming, so there are no specific rules.

> [**1 Timothy 2:9, 10** (NWT)](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/study-bible/books/1-timothy/2/#v54002009-v54002010)
>
> <sup>**9**</sup> Likewise, the women should adorn themselves in **appropriate dress, with modesty and soundness of mind,** not with styles of hair braiding and gold or pearls or very expensive clothing, <sup>**10**</sup> but in the way that is proper for women professing devotion to God, namely, through good works.

You can observe what JWs look like around the world in the side-scrolling images on [jw.org](https://jw.org).

---

In terms of symbolic objects, Jehovah's Witnesses use unleavened bread and red wine as symbols during the [Memorial of Jesus' Death](https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/memorial/) once each year.

Answer (score 4):

No, they have no need for special robes or vestments, and neither do they have any sacred or symbolic objects that are used in worship.  They do not have ordained ministers or any sort of clergy class and would be likened to "lay preachers" who volunteer to preach and to teach.

Men and women dress modestly and when they go from door to door, they look like ordinary, everyday people with the men in suits and the women in skirts or dresses.

If you went into a Kingdom Hall to attend their meetings, you would not see any stained glass windows, crosses, images of Jesus or Mary or the Apostles, and no altar adorned with gold or brass candelabra or chalices.